# How to Implement buttons in a cloud like structure in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Does any one know how I can arrange a given number of buttons in a cloud like structure? Is there a library which I can already use? Or what is the best and most simple way of rearranging the buttons in such a manner?

I would like it to look like these pages:

[[image]]

[image]

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Wrap-class.html